# Choosing an image from gallery with espresso

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso

I've been reading into espresso but there aren't many resources available to learn the complex operations. I have an activity where you click an imagebutton and takes you to your library where you can choose a picture, and that picture is displayed in an imageview in that same activity.
How would you ask espresso to choose any picture in my gallery and then making sure it's displayed in the image view?

Comment: Did you solved it?